Teams bot losing permission after Azure function deployment
I’ve created a Teams bot that sends messages to our customers. While the bot itself works fine, we’re facing a significant operability issue: any action performed on the Azure Function hosting the bot causes us to lose access to our customers. This means we can’t send them messages unless they uninstall and reinstall the app.
For example, deploying code changes (even for minor fixes like adding debug information or addressing security vulnerabilities) using the VSCode Teams Toolkit revokes our bot's permissions. Additionally, when we upgraded our service plan to a premium tier yesterday, the Azure Function moved to a new instance, and we lost access again—despite no changes to the code or permissions.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution?
Thank you,
Lior

I sent a httpRequest directly to the Azure function and received the message on Teams
I deployed the code using VSCode Teams toolkit, without changing the code
I sent another httpRequest that failed (did not find my member object)

const member = await notificationApp.notification.findMember(
      //findMember is expecting a function that returns a predicate. therefore, we must use async function
      //to return a promise that resolves to a predicate (even if the actual operation is synchronous)
      async (m) =>
        (m.account.userPrincipalName.toLowerCase() === userEmail.toLowerCase() || 
                    m.account.email?.toLowerCase() === userEmail.toLowerCase())
    ).catch((error) => {
      context.log.error(`Error finding member ${userEmail}:`, error);
    });


I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, everything started working again


It seems the similar cause to MS Teams bot created using Teams toolkit does not find installations or members
From the FAQ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/interactive-notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#faq):

Notification target connections are stored in the persistence storage. If you're using the default local file storage, Azure web app and Azure Functions clean up the local file during a restart or redeploy.

To resolve, use your own shared storage for production environment. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/interactive-notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#add-storage
